# jpegencoder.swc from http://last.instinct.se/graphics-and-effects/using-the-fast-asynchronous-alchemy-jpeg-encoder-in-flash/640

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

Has anyone succesfully used this encoder in flashbuilder 4.5.1?
I'm getting this error??? usually on loading up a second pic. any help is appreciated.

```
RangeError: Error #1506: The specified range is invalid. 
at cmodule.aircall::FSM_imalloc$/start() 
at cmodule.aircall::FSM_pubrealloc/work() 
at cmodule.aircall::CRunner/work() 
at Function/<anonymous>() 
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch() 
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

my code is as follows:

```
private var im:img; 
private var jpgStream:ByteArray; 
private var jpeglib:Object; 
private var jpeginit:CLibInit = new CLibInit(); // get library 

public function save_image(_im:img, pg:Number):void 
{ 
     var bm:BitmapData = Bitmap(_im.getChildAt(0)).bitmapData; 
     im = _im; 

     var imgData:ByteArray = bm.getPixels(bm.rect); 
     jpgStream = new ByteArray(); 
     imgData.position = 0; 

     trace(bm == null); 
     var jpegQuality:Number = 40; 

     if (!jpeglib) { 
          jpeglib=jpeginit.init(); 
     } 
     jpeglib.encodeAsync(encodeComplete, imgData, jpgStream, bm.width, bm.height, jpegQuality); 
} 

private function encodeComplete(e:Event):void { 
     trace("Encoding complete"); 

     file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Pic-A-Note/" + albumName + "/object_layer_" + im.name + ".pn"); 
     fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE); 
     fs.writeBytes(jpgStream,0); 
     fs.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing the CLibInit twice. I've created a custom class to handle encode of jpg's transparently using jpegencoder.swc, like you do with the native class.

```
public class JPGAlchemyEncoder {

    private static var alchemyWrapper:Object;
    private var quality:Number;

    public function JPGAlchemyEncoder(quality:Number) {
        this.quality = quality;
        if (!alchemyWrapper){
            var loader:CLibInit = new CLibInit;
            alchemyWrapper = loader.init();
        }
    }

    public function encode(bitmapData:BitmapData):ByteArray{
        var data: ByteArray = bitmapData.clone().getPixels( bitmapData.rect );
        data.position = 0;
        return alchemyWrapper.write_jpeg_file(data, bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height, 3, 2, quality);
    }

    public function encodeAsync(bitmapData:BitmapData, completeHandler:Function):void{
        var encodedData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var data: ByteArray = bitmapData.clone().getPixels(bitmapData.rect);
        data.position = 0;
        var encodeComplete:Function = function():void{
            completeHandler(encodedData);
        };
        alchemyWrapper.encodeAsync(encodeComplete, data, encodedData, bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height, quality);
    }
}
}
```

Check how the constructor deal with the static CLib. This way you can start as many JPGAlchemyEncoder's as you want but the CLib will be initialized only once, solving your problem.

Comment: Ahh this makes a lot of sense. Though I came to this conclusion myself by now I still think this is a useful post for those that may come across this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used that swc, but the non-alchemy jpeg encoder in AS3Corelib will do the job just as well (without any errors, I might add)
http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/